# Can't delete File because it's used by another process, even though Stream was closed

Tags: java

I have this class that is responsible for serializing/encrypting and decrypting/deserializing a given object.

```java
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SerializingUtils {
    public static void serialize(User user, String password, String filePath) {
        SecretKey key = makeKey(password);

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(user, cipher);

            ObjectOutputStream stream = createOutputStream(filePath, cipher);

            stream.writeObject(sealedObject);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static User deserialize(String filePath, String password) throws StreamCorruptedException, Exception {
        SecretKey key = makeKey(password);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        ObjectInputStream stream = createInputStream(filePath, cipher);

        SealedObject sealedObject = (SealedObject) stream.readObject();

        stream.close();

        return (User) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
    }

    private static SecretKey makeKey(String password) {
        return new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "Blowfish");
    }

    private static ObjectOutputStream createOutputStream(String filePath, Cipher cipher) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream);
        CipherOutputStream cipherStream = new CipherOutputStream(bufferedStream, cipher);
        return new ObjectOutputStream(cipherStream);
    }

    private static ObjectInputStream createInputStream(String filePath, Cipher cipher) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileStream);
        CipherInputStream cipherStream = new CipherInputStream(bufferedStream, cipher);
        return new ObjectInputStream(cipherStream);
    }
}
```

It works just fine. I tried writing some tests for it:

```java
public class SerializingUtilsTest {
    private String path;
    private User user;
    private String password;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        path = FileUtils.getAppFolder() + File.separator + "test_file.pman";
        user = new User("Josh");
        password = "drAkE";

        SerializingUtils.serialize(user, password, path);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionIfPasswordIsWrong() {
        assertThrows(StreamCorruptedException.class, () -> {
            SerializingUtils.deserialize(path, "drake");
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAUserWithCorrectName() throws Exception {
        User obtainedUser = SerializingUtils.deserialize(path, password);

        assertEquals(user.getName(), obtainedUser.getName());
    }
}
```

It's pretty much an integration test: it calls the actual method and test what happens when the user inputs the correct/wrong password. The test also runs fine. But then I tried implementing a tear down method to delete the created file once the test was done:

```java
@After
public void tearDown() {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(path);

    try {
        Files.delete(filePath);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, the tear down method throws this exception when it's called (2 times):

```java
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\dev\passman\test_file.pman: The file is already being used by another process
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1146)
    at com.passman.utils.SerializingUtilsTest.tearDown(SerializingUtilsTest.java:49)
```

Maybe the `FileStream`s used to build `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` aren't being closed, even though I call `close` on them. I wonder if `bufferedStream` and `cipherStream` remain open too. Anyways, the real question here is, how can I ensure all the streams inside `createOutputStream()` and `createInputStream()` are closed once I don't need them anymore? Can I close a stream right after passing it as an argument to another type of stream, or is it still being used by reference?

The dependencies of my code, if anybody wants to test the entire thing:

```
// User.java
public class User implements Serializable {
    private final String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

```
// FileUtils.java
public class FileUtils {
    public static String getAppFolder() {
        try {
            return new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a `FileSystemException`.. are you sure you're not having that file opened in some editor (or other application) trying to watch its content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your stream remains open if an exception is thrown between the moment it is opened and the moment it is closed.

```
 public static User deserialize(String filePath, String password) throws StreamCorruptedException, Exception {
            SecretKey key = makeKey(password);
    
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    
// stream opens here
            ObjectInputStream stream = createInputStream(filePath, cipher);
// something goes wrong here  and exception is thrown  
            SealedObject sealedObject = (SealedObject) stream.readObject();
// this doesn't happen...    
            stream.close();
    
            return (User) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
}
```

----- TRY THIS -----

```
try(var stream = createInputStream(filePath, cipher)) {
// read your object and process it. this is a try-with-resources clause so it auto-closes your stream.
} catch (Exception ex) {
// handle exceptions here (or re-throw them)
}
```